# Server.Transfer Issue in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one page called default.aspx . On that page I have one button click handler like
In that handler I am usng Server.Transfer to transfer to next page on server . Suppose that page is newPage.aspx. In that page I have one button control that button control is not firing in first click . it is firing in second click

Comment: show some code what you tried

Comment: default.aspx button_click(object sender,eventarg e) {Servr.Transfer('other.aspx')  }     other.aspx button_click(object sender,eventargs e){ Response.write('arya')           }

Comment: avoid `server.transfer` and find some other way to make your logic. The click will be eaten.